# C# pattern matching analogue of Rust match/case with destructuring

Tags: c#, rust, switch-statement, pattern-matching

In `rust` you can do things like this:

```rust
for n in 1..101 {
  let triple = (n % 5, n % 2, n % 7);
  match triple {
    // Destructure the second and third elements
    (0, y, z) => println!("First is `0`, `y` is {:?}, and `z` is {:?}", y, z),
    (1, ..)  => println!("First is `1` and the rest doesn't matter"),
    (.., 2)  => println!("last is `2` and the rest doesn't matter"),
    (3, .., 4)  => println!("First is `3`, last is `4`, and the rest doesn't matter"),
    // `..` can be used to ignore the rest of the tuple
    _      => println!("It doesn't matter what they are"),
    // `_` means don't bind the value to a variable
  };
}
```

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: note that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896431/c-sharp-equivalent-of-rusts-match), a possible duplicate, does not address destructuring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since C# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-9), the language has supported [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching), overview of the pattern syntax can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns).

Using this as a reference, it's easy to implement very similar functionality for each of the above cases in C#:

```cs
foreach (int n in Enumerable.Range(0, 101)) {
  Console.WriteLine((n % 5, n % 2, n % 7) switch {
    (0, var y, var z) => $"First is `0`, `y` is {y}, and `z` is {z}",
    (1, _, _) => "First is `1` and the rest doesn't matter",
    (_, _, 2)  => "last is `2` and the rest doesn't matter",
    (3, _, 4)  => "First is `3`, last is `4`, and the rest doesn't matter",
    _      => "It doesn't matter what they are",
  });
}
```

Couple things of particular note here:

1. We must consume the result of the `switch` expression.
   For instance, this causes an error:

```cs
foreach (int n in Enumerable.Range(0, 101)) {
  // causes: 
  //   error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, 
  //       decrement, await, and new object expressions 
  //       can be used as a statement
  (n % 5, n % 2, n % 7) switch {
    (0, var y, var z) => Console.WriteLine($"First is `0`, `y` is {y}, and `z` is {z}"),
    (1, _, _)  => Console.WriteLine("First is `1` and the rest doesn't matter"),
    (_, _, 2)  => Console.WriteLine("last is `2` and the rest doesn't matter"),
    (3, _, 4)  => Console.WriteLine("First is `3`, last is `4`, and the rest doesn't matter"),
    _      => Console.WriteLine("It doesn't matter what they are"),
  };
}
```

2. If we want to use `..` to throw away 0 or more positional items, we'll need [C# 11.0 or greater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#list-patterns), and we'd need to instantiate it as a `List` or `array` instead, and switch to using square brackets `[]` rather than parentheses `()`, like so:

```cs
foreach (int n in Enumerable.Range(0, 101)) {
  // this can also be any of: 
  //      `new int[] { n % 5, n % 2, n % 7 }`, 
  //      `new[] { n % 5, n % 2, n % 7 }`, 
  //      `{ n % 5, n % 2, n % 7 }`
  Console.WriteLine(new List<int> { n % 5, n % 2, n % 7 } switch {
    [0, var y, var z] => $"First is `0`, `y` is {y}, and `z` is {z}",
    [1, ..] => "First is `1` and the rest doesn't matter",
    [.., 2] => "last is `2` and the rest doesn't matter",
    [3, .., 4] => "First is `3`, last is `4`, and the rest doesn't matter",
    _ => "It doesn't matter what they are",
  });
}
```

Comment: C# actually has a [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement) and a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression). You are using the latter here. Also, instead of `String.Format`, you could use [String interpolation using $](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Create an array: `int[] input = { n % 5, n % 2, n % 7 };`. Note that this not an array literal but an array initializer.

Comment: Thanks for the good points, @OlivierJacot-Descombes I've incorporated what I think you've meant there. It doesn't seem like I've made the mistake of calling the initializer syntax a literal, but the difference between them is new to me! Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921844/how-to-return-an-array-literal-in-c-sharp#comment69345846_10921844)

Comment: You have not made any mistakes. It was meant as suggestions and clarifications. Maybe we will see this in C#12: [Proposal: Collection literals #5354](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5354).